# Understanding Firestore's Underlying Serialisation Mechanism

Tags: scala, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to get some information on how the serialisation/deserialisation mechanism works in Firestore. The issue I am having is that I am passing a Scala (JVM language) object into the Firestore create method but it blows up at the point of serialising that data. After some investigation, it appears that Firestore requires values created from classes which have an empty public constructor, why is this a constraint? This is something that Scala classes do not have. Is there anyway to side-step Firestore's serialisation and provide my own?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Firestore requires values created from classes which have an empty public constructor, why is this a constraint?

When you load data from Firestore, you have the option to read a Java object from the document by calling [`DocumentSnapshot.toObject(Class<T> valueType)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#toObject(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)). In order to create the object that it returns, the Firestore SDK must be able to call a constructor on the class that you pass in. And the only constructor it can reasonably call, is one without any arguments, as it has no way to determine what argument values to pass in otherwise.

Note that calling `toObject` is not the only option to create an object out of a `DocumentSnapshot`. You can also construct the Java object yourself, and extract the individual values from the snapshot by calling its [`get` methods](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#get(java.lang.String)).

---

A quick search seems to hint that it **is** possible to add a no-argument constructor in Scala too, so I also recommend checking out:

- [Scala case classes with new firebase-server-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38533778/scala-case-classes-with-new-firebase-server-sdk)
- [A quick overview of using Firebase in a Scala application](https://medium.com/@RICEaaron/scala-firebase-da433df93bd2)

Comment: Thank you! I have resorted to adding an empty constructor as follows: final case class Foo(s : String){
  def this() = this("")
}

Comment: This compiles down to a Java class with an empty constructor.

Comment: Great to hear! I haven't done Scala myself (despite large chunks of the Realtime Database being written in it), so couldn't come up with a quick example like that.

Comment: FYI, I am writing a purely functional Scala client library for firestore here https://github.com/mikail-khan/zio-gcp